# How to navigate multiple Google maps panoramas using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I have been experimenting with Google Maps playing with custom panoramas. At the tutorial on Google Maps API page they give a simple example on how to add one custom panorama.

Lets say I have two panorama pictures A and B. the first panorama I want to show is 'A'.

Javascript for navigating between the two panorama is:

```
var panorama

function initialize()
{
  var panoOptions = {
    pano: 'A',
    visible: true,
    panoProvider: getCustomPanorama }

  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('pano_canvas'),panoOptions);
}

function getCustomPanorama(pano,zoom,tileX,tileY)
{
   if(pano == "A") 
   { 
      return {
        location: {
          pano: 'A',
          description: "Some description for A",
          latLng: // Google maps latLng for A
        },
        links: 
        [{
          heading: ... // Directions to B
          description: "Some description to B",
          pano: "B",
        }],
        tiles: { ... }
      }
   }
   else // We show panorama B
   {
     return {
       location: {
         pano: "B"
         description: ...
         latLng: ...
       }
       links: [{
         heading: ... ,
         description: ...,
         pano: "A";
       }]
       tiles: { ... }
     }
   }
}
```

However I would like to extend on the tutorial using AJAX, since the IF-ELSEIF-ELSE switch statements get rather tedious to maintain if I have a larger sample of panoramas.

For argument sake - lets say 30! :-)

I have made a simple webservice that given panoramaID "A" will return the relevant location, links and tiles given in the IF statement above. The idea is to call that webservice using AJAX - and update the panorama on the webpage with the new location, links and tiles.

Now this is where I hit a wall:

I can load the first panorama, but i can't navigate to the next panoram using the link i have for it.

What I did was:

replace getCustomPanorama() with handling code:

```
var ajax_panorama = {};

function initialize()
{
  var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "http://www.mydomain.com/MyPanoramaUrl";
  http.open("GET", url, true);
  http.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200)
    {
        var object = "(" + http.responseText + ")";
        ajax_panorama = eval(object);
        var panoOptions = { ... } // As before
        panorama = ... ;
    }
  }
  http.send(null);
}

function getCustomPanorama(pano,zoom,tileX,tileY)
{
   return ajax_panorama;
}
```

I have tried putting the AJAX code down in getCustomPanorama(), but that did no good, and trying to handle it by listening to "pano_changed" event didn't help either. As far as i see it: It all comes down to the asynchronus part about AJAX...

Any ideas to a better approach?

---

UPDATE: My learning about AJAX in general resulted in the hint being: **Turn async mode off!**

Since the general idea for my webservice was to return a JSON object, that could be parsed to Google Maps API. My attempt would then be something like:

```
var panorama

function initialize()
{
  var panoOptions = {
    pano: 'A',
    visible: true,
    panoProvider: getCustomPanorama 
  }

  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('pano_canvas'),panoOptions);
}


function getCustomPanorama(pano,zoom,tileX,tileY)
{
  var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "http://www.mydomain.com/MyPanoramaUrl?pano="+pano;
  http.open("GET", url, false);
  var ajaxPano = eval("(" + http.responseText + ")");

  return ajaxPano;
}
```

Comment: Corrected a few typos, so its easyer to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question but i stumbled across this while trying to fix a problem just like this. This can be easily fixed if you set the async flag to false by doing something like this:

http.open("GET", url, false); instead of http.open("GET", url, true);

This solved the problem for me.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah I learned the same down the road, when I revisted AJAX in another project. 

Anyhow I never came around working with Google Maps API again, but I did learn more more about AJAX in general.

To summaraize my project. The idea was that whenever I needed to call my webservice to get a new streetview picture, then the webservice would return a JSON with all the relevant links and parameters which could be parsed more-or-less strait to Google Maps API.

Adjustment added to topic above. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have almost the right idea, with a few problems:

1. It sounds like your webservice requires the ID of a panorama, but you never pass it one.
2. The getCustomPanorama function must return straight away, so you can't make an AJAX call (because AJAX calls are asynchronous and may return later).

Here is how I would solve it:

- Modify your webservice to return a Javascript object containing all the information for all your panorama's, keyed on ID e.g.

  panoramas = {
      A: { /* The first panorama */ },
      B: { /* Another panorama */ }
  };

Keep the rest of your code as is, except modify getCustomPanorama as follows:

```
function getCustomPanorama(pano,zoom,tileX,tileY) {
   return ajax_panorama[pano];
}
```

This takes the ID of the panorama you are navigating to, and looks it up in the object you passed back from the server. Because the object finishes downloading before you construct the panorama, getCustomPanorama can return straight away.

For a much larger set of panoramas (thousands) you may want to be tricker and use an AJAX call in getCustomPanorama, but for fewer than 100 downloading the entire description of your panorama graph in advance will be fine.

Comment: Well atm im just constructing each panorama on server side, and the idea was that whenever a link is triggered in the panorama via for instance the 'links_changed' or 'pano_changed' event, AJAX woud get a new panorama from the server.

Though im have a bit of a problem making the code work...